# Most efficient use of constants from main file in module.exports. (Discord.js)

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js, node-modules

I may be overthinking the situation, but I've been reading through the discord.js guide and making a database (Using sequelize and sqlite3). Typically, I create discord bots using 1 file since they're usually pretty simple bots. I am working on a more complex bot and would like to split commands into multiple files using module.exports. However, I wanted to see what was the best way to use constants declared in my main file.

Here's a snippet of bot.js:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Sequelize = require('sequelize');
const { prefix, token } = require('./config.json');

const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

const commandFiles = fs.readdirSync('./commands').filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));

for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
// Sequelize Database Initialization
const sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'user', 'password', {
    host: 'localhost',
    dialect: 'sqlite',
    logging: false,
    // SQLite only
    storage: 'database.sqlite',
});

// Sequelize Database Model
const Tags = sequelize.define('tags', {
    name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING,
        unique: true,
    },
    description: Sequelize.TEXT,
    username: Sequelize.STRING,
    usage_count: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        defaultValue: 0,
        allowNull: false,
    },
});

client.on('ready', async () => {
  console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`);
  // Sync Sequelize Database
  Tags.sync();
});

client.on('message', async message => {
    if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) || message.author.bot) return;

    const args = message.content.slice(prefix.length).split(/ +/);
    const commandName = args.shift().toLowerCase();

    const command = client.commands.get(commandName) || client.commands.find(cmd => cmd.aliases && cmd.aliases.includes(commandName));

    if (!command) return;

    if (command.args && !args.length) {
        return message.channel.send(`You didn't provide any arguments, ${message.author}!`);
    }

    try {
        await command.execute(message, args, api, util, db, prefix);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
        message.reply('there was an error trying to execute that command!');
    }
});

client.login(token);
```

Here's the addtag.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'addtag',
    description: 'Add Tags to a database.',
    args: true,
    aliases: ['addTag', 'add'],
    async execute(message, args) {
        const tagName = args[0]
        const tagDescription = args[1]

        try {
            // equivalent to: INSERT INTO tags (name, description, username) values (?, ?, ?);
            const tag = await Tags.create({
                name: tagName,
                description: tagDescription,
                username: message.author.username,
            });
            return message.reply(`Tag ${tag.name} added.`);
        }
        catch (e) {
            if (e.name === 'SequelizeUniqueConstraintError') {
                return message.reply('That tag already exists.');
            }
            return message.reply('Something went wrong with adding a tag.');
        }
    },
};
```

This won't run properly because "Tags" is not defined in the module.exports. I know I can declare it at the beginning of the file, but is there a more efficient way to do so since it's already in bot.js?

Comment: You can attach to client instance and make it easier to access, 
`<Client>.sequelize = code` then u can do `<Client>.sequelize`, its the same way as u do for your commands and aliases

Comment: Thank you very much. I believe I got it working now with your suggestion.